# Article : A or The

Tags: articles

- *The/A* French make many delicious sorts of cheese.
- *The/A* bird has two wings

Which is correct? Which article is used to refer a whole group of people.

Answer (score 2):

For the first one, only "the" works.

For the second, both "the" and "a" are correct, but they mean different things. "The bird has two wings" is about some specific bird while "a bird has two wings" is about birds in general. You could also say "birds have two wings" or "every bird has two wings" etc.

The difference is that "A French" by itself, isn't right, because "French" is an adjective, not a noun. If you change it to "French person" or "French people" then you could use either "a" or "the".

Comment: "a French people" would not work because it disagrees on number. (Insert caveat about one of many Gallic tribes or some similar construction, but that's probably not what is intended.)

Answer (score 1):

Generally the definite article 'the" is used to refer to a group as a group:

> - The French are noted for their consumption of wine.
> - The rich are often assumed to be arrogant.
> - The beach is a popular summer destination.
> - The Jews have often been persecuted.
> - The educated often think of themselves as a natural elite.

But when referring to a single but typical member of a group, the indefinite article "A" or "an" is used.

> - A horse has a single toe on each foot, which forms the hoof.
> - A New-Yorker is often presumed to be forever busy.
> - A professor is responsible for teaching students.
> - A building will have at least one door.

Note that both forms, particularly when used for groups of people (or typical members of such groups) lend themselves to stereotypes. One should be careful about these, they can be inaccurate, and are sometimes offensive.

The late Stephan Jay  Gould used to object strongly in his essays to the casual use of "the" forms for taxonomic groups. He wrote "There is no such thing as **the snake** or **the beetle**. Each group includes thousands of species, some quite different from each other."